# I cannot figure out a way that will give an error message if user accidentally inputs a letter other than A B C D or F

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

```
using System;

    namespace gpa
    {
        class gpa
        {
            static void Main(string [] args)
            {
                double credit = 0;
                double totalCreditHours = 0;

            char grade = ' ';
            double gradePoints = 0;
            double totalGradePoints = 0;

            int counter = 0;
            double gpa = 0;

            do 
            {
                Console.Write("Enter letter grade for class #{0} \n(use A, B, C, or D. Type 0 after all classes entered.): ", counter += 1);
                char userInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (userInput == '0')
                {
                    break;
                }

                else 
                {
                    grade = userInput;
                    Console.Write("Enter your credit hours: ");
                    credit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                    switch (grade)
                    {
                        case 'A': gradePoints = 4;
                            break;
                        case 'B': gradePoints = 3;
                            break;
                        case 'C': gradePoints = 2;
                            break;
                        case 'D': gradePoints = 1;
                            break;

                    }

                    totalGradePoints = totalGradePoints + (credit * gradePoints);
                    totalCreditHours = totalCreditHours + credit;

                } 

            } while (grade != 0);

                gpa = CalculateGPA(totalGradePoints, totalCreditHours);
                Console.Write("Your GPA is ", gpa);

                Console.ReadKey();
            }


            static double CalculateGPA(double totalGradePoints, double totalCreditHours)
            {
                return (totalGradePoints / totalCreditHours);

            }
        }
    }
```

--I have tried a default case and i have tried another `if` statement, but i cant get it to work. I just need it to say "Error, invalid input" if user types a letter other than `A B C D F`.

Comment: Can't you set your default case to Console.WriteLine("Error, invalid input"); return 0;

Comment: I think there is a purpose why there is `do-while` loop in the first place. Try to change the while condition to check if user input wrong value. In addition, put default case as having `Console.WriteLine("Error, invalid input!");` as well

Comment: this isnt working, i have this error--"Control cannot fall through from one case label"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could filter the letter grade input and if you don't like it, then ask for another letter:

```
Console.Write("Enter letter grade for class #{0} \n(use A, B, C, or D. Type 0 after all classes entered.): ", counter += 1);
char userInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if ( !"ABCDF".ToCharArray().Contains(userInput) )
{
Console.WriteLine("Enter valid letter" ); 
continue; // Start's the do loop over 
}
// You now have a good letter, A, B, ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
do 
{
   Console.Write("Enter letter grade for class #{0} \n(use A, B, C, or D. Type 0 after all classes entered.): ", counter += 1);
                char userInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                if (userInput == '0')
                {
                    break;
                }

                else 
                {
                    grade = userInput;
                    Console.Write("Enter your credit hours: ");
                    credit = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    bool throwErrorMsg = false;
                    switch (grade)
                    {
                        case 'A': gradePoints = 4;
                            break;
                        case 'B': gradePoints = 3;
                            break;
                        case 'C': gradePoints = 2;
                            break;
                        case 'D': gradePoints = 1;
                            break;
                        default: throwErrorMsg = true;
                            break;
                    }
                    if (throwErrorMsg)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Error...");
                        break;
                    }
                    totalGradePoints = totalGradePoints + (credit * gradePoints);
                    totalCreditHours = totalCreditHours + credit;

                } 

            } while (grade != 0);
```